# Solve can't handle e^r (Sin[ArcCos[e^(-r) Log[r]]]) == ArcCos[Log[r]]

Tags: equation-solving

When I evaluate this expression

```
Solve[e^r (Sin[ArcCos[e^(-r) Log[r]]]) == ArcCos[Log[r]]]
```

Mathematica tells me

> Solve: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

whereas Wolfram|Alpha can find a simple nice answer.

> `r = 0.687950`

Comment: `Solve[]` is not sufficiently able to handle transcendental equations, unless one restricts the search domain: `Solve[Exp[r] (Sin[ArcCos[Exp[-r] Log[r]]]) == ArcCos[Log[r]] && 0 < r < 1, r]`. (Note that `e` has no built-in meaning in *Mathematica*; use `E` for the constant, or the function `Exp[]`.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
FindRoot[Exp[r] (Sin[ArcCos[Exp[-r] Log[r]]]) == ArcCos[Log[r]], {r, 
  1}]



   (*  {r -> 0.688}  *)
```

Have fun!